# Select jQuery plugin dynamically

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have a set of jquery plugins as follows:-

```
fooADD(options)
fooSUB(options)
fooDIV(options)
....
```

I then have a plugin that acts on a  with an attribute data-plugin=""

So for:-

```
<DIV data-plugin="fooADD">
```

I want to run the code:-

```
var item = $('<div/>').fooADD({'option':'value'});
```

How can I achieve this such that I can keep adding new foo plugins which can be selected from `data-plugin` without the need to update an array of function lookups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/zYfWc/

```
var plugin = $('div').data('plugin');
var item = $('<div/>')[plugin]({'option':'value'});
```